# C/C++ Macro that manipulate string during compilation time

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a macro which creates a global variable that is created during compilation time:

```
DECLARE_VAR(temp)
#define DECLARE_VAR(temp)  \
  extern unsigned char temp ##_start;\
  extern unsigned char temp ##_end;
```

What I need to do is creating a variable with uppercase of the give "temp" which I send to the macro, in the example I want to have "TEMP_start, TEMP_end" variables

I can't change the macro call to DECLARE_VAR(TEMP)

Is it possible?

EDIT: more information

I'm working with a very big system which I can only edit parts of it.

My case:
I have ~500 users which needs to define ~10 variables to use my lib.
The compiler is creating those variables because they are the output of an external script.

We don't want to make a lot of changes in our system aka edit ~500 users and declaring 10 variables each. so the easiest way for them is just adding DECLARE_VAR(temp) and call func(USE_VAR) which spreads those vars.

Comment: No it's not possible, and it must be said, it seems like a really misguided thing to want to do. What's your overall aim? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My compilation creates the global variables in different formats, some with upper case name and some with lower case name, I want to have only one DECLARE_VAR for those variables.
I can't change the compilation outputs

Comment: Yes but why do you feel the need to use macros? Why don't you want to declare the global variables in the normal way? What do you think you are gaining by using macros?

Comment: I have many variable which are created using this macro (except _start, _end), and I don't want the user of my lib to know about them (I have many users as well), they just need to say that they want them by using the macro

Comment: maybe you think those are good reasons but they arent. As  a user of a library I would always prefer to write c or c++ when declaring variables instead of using some macros that does that for me. It is really not clear at all how `DECLARE_VAR(TEMP)` is any better than writing the declarations directly. Maybe you can give an example of usage?

Comment: Please provide more context what and why you are trying to achieve something. It is highly probable that there is an alternative solution.

Comment: Well as I said it's not possible to manipulate the case of a string using macros. I would suggest redesigning your API, so that a user of your library can access the global variables using that API, something like `value = get_global_value(name),` `set_global_value(name, new_value);`, or whatever. Generally macros are best avoided.

Comment: When I see you have wrote `My compilation creates the global variables` this imminently raises red flag in my head. Global variables are source of evil code. Also looks like that you have problem with understanding encapsulation `I have many variable which are created using this macro (except _start, _end)`.

Comment: Looks like you should first read about [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and then rephrase question.

Comment: If you need to do codegen that involves changing the case of names, you need to do your codegen with something other than the preprocessor. If you're not willing to do that, you need to adapt to what the preprocessor _can_ do.

Comment: "_I have ~500 users which needs to define ~10 variables to use my lib_" - and why is that? Shouldn't you redesign the lib so that isn't needed instead?

Comment: When I see an update I have no doubts something vary bad happened with your library architecture. Number of library users should not have impact on how many internal variables library have. Also still you didn't provide information which can resolve `XY problem` your question have. You should write about business logic which those variables should provide.

Answer (score 2):

> What I need to do is creating a variable with uppercase of the give "temp" [...]
>
> I  can't change the macro call to DECLARE_VAR(TEMP)
>
> Is it possible?

No.